# normality of independent variables

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, normality-assumption

I am running a generalized linear model. The dependent variable is binomial and independent variables are categorical and continuous variables. My question is :
1. Does the continuous independent variable have to be normally distributed? 
2. Do I need to check for the normality of residuals of the continuous variables?

[image]                                            [image]
These are images of the model residuals. The model is as follows.
B and A are categorical variables with two levels each and F is continuous.

```
t1<-glm(B ~ A + F, family = binomial, data = d, na.action = "na.fail")
sm<-standardize(t1)
model.set<-dredge(sm)
model.set
top.model<-get.models(model.set, subset=delta<2)
top.model
#model averaging
u<-summary(model.avg(top.model), revised.var = T)
u
confint(u, full = T)
plot(density(resid(t1))) 
qqnorm(resid(t1)) 
qqline(resid(t1))
```

@Harlan Nelson, I have added the graphs.

Comment: Can you let us know what your model is?

Comment: A glm is a regression model, and **do not make any distribvutional assumptions about the predictors/independent variables**.

Comment: @Harlan Nelson. Here B and A are categorical with two levels, F is continuous.                                                                                                     
    <t1<-glm(B ~ A + F, family = binomial, data = d, na.action = "na.fail")
    sm<-standardize(t1)
    model.set<-dredge(sm)
    model.set
    top.model<-get.models(model.set, subset=delta<2)
    top.model
    plot(density(resid(t1))) 
    qqnorm(resid(t1)) 
    qqline(resid(t1))>

Comment: If your model states that they are normal then they should be.  If the model assumes that they are just fixed values, then there really is no distribution.  Many GLM models, and yours it seems,  only require that some transformation of the error term to be normal. It is possible to write models in any way you want.